# Persist files using zeppelin notebooks on docker

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I´m running zeppelin on Docker and mounting a volumen there to persist the notes I´m working on.
For that I´m using the following code:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 8080:8080 -v C:\my_dir\zeppelin_notebook:/zeppelin/notebook  -e ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0 --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
```

The issue is that altough this keeps the notes, I´m not able to stores/read files from zeppein even if I copy them into the same folder I have the notes.

E.G. If I list the files in the directory:

```
list.dirs(path = "notebook/")
```

I get some like:

```
[1] “notebook/”                      “notebook//2ETUM43DN”
 [3] “notebook//2EUWCDDP7”            “notebook//2EVMR55HQ”
 [5] “notebook//.git”                 “notebook//.git/branches”
 [7] “notebook//.git/hooks”           “notebook//.git/logs”
 [9] “notebook//.git/logs/refs”       “notebook//.git/logs/refs/heads”
[11] “notebook//.git/objects”         “notebook//.git/objects/info”
[13] “notebook//.git/objects/pack”    “notebook//.git/refs”
[15] “notebook//.git/refs/heads”      “notebook//.git/refs/tags”
```

Which does not shown the text files I have copied there.

The issue seems to be happeding with R only:

[image]

With Python it is working fine:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're using `list.dirs()` which will only show you directories in your path. You should use `list.file()` to get files. Use the `pattern` parameter if you only want to get certain files.